# Слово "щи"

Tags: этимология, морфемный-разбор

Тут как-то задали смешной вопрос по поводу единственного числа слова "щи". Но шутки шутками, а слово интересное. Во-первых, какой у него корень? Одна буква "щ", а что тогда "и", окончание? И, во-вторых, традиционный вопрос о происхождении этого слова.
Щи - это суп из капусты, но для капустного супа есть более понятное слово "капустняк". А что же тогда щи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется, был уже такой вопрос.
Но искать трудно, повторюсь
Единственное число нормативно отсутсвует (это все знают), но форма восстанавливается по родительному падежу. Щей - значит женский род, третье склонение -ЩЬ.
От ЩА было бы род. мн. был бы - Щ. А от мужского рода Щ - Щёв.

Корень, естественно, Щ (если не копаться в дебрях синхронистического подхода).

С этимологий вопрос несколько спорный, достоверно известно, что исходно щами называли все жидкое и кислое (побродившее). Потом - напиток (известный ныне как "кислые Щи")

Происходит от неустановленной формы; русск. щи, диал. шти «похлебка из сушеной рыбы и крупы» и др. возводят к *сътъ, мн. съти (ср. сот), др.-русск. съто «пропитание». Предполагают также родство со щаве́ль, др.-русск. щавьнъ, т. е. из* съчь : сок. Еще одна версия предполагает усеченное *борщи от борщ. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера  с комментариями О. Н. Трубачёва; см. Список литературы.